# Too many arguments for move_and_slide() call

Tags: gd, godot, gdscript

```
extends CharacterBody2D

var speed = 150
var jumpforce = 500
var gravity = 700

var vel = Vector2()

func _physics_process(delta):
    if Input.is_action_pressed("player_left"):
        vel.x -= speed
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("player_right"):
        vel.x += speed
    
    move_and_slide(vel, Vector2.UP)
```

Why Error??? Error: Too many arguments for move_and_slide() call. Expected at most 0 but received 2.

I watched the guide how to make games on godot but on the guide 3 version of the engine and I sit on 4 and since I do not know almost the basics of the engine and gdscript I find it difficult to solve the problem yourself can you help?

Comment: In v4 `move_and_slide` doesn't take any arguments. See the [docs](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/physics/physics_introduction.html#move-and-slide)

Answer (score 0):

In version 4, velocity is now a node property, along with up_direction, etc.
And `move_and_slide()` now takes no arguments. In your code, replace this:

```
move_and_slide(vel, Vector2.UP)
```

With this:

```
move_and_slide()
```

Also remove your `vel` variable and update as follows:

```
velocity.x += speed
```

And it should work.